# Installing QGIS public key

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, gpgpu

I have been trying to install QGIS LTR on Ubuntu 22.04 but it comes up with the issues below.  I have attached my code commands as well below.

I need help figuring out what I am doing wrong.

```
Code:
sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-common


cd $HOME

wget https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./qgis-archive-keyring.gpg --import
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./qgis-archive-keyring.gpg --list-keys  

sudo mkdir -m755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings 


sudo cp qgis-archive-keyring.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg

cd $HOME



sudo cp -f $HOME/qgis.sources /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

sudo apt update

sudo apt install netcdf4

sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass python3-qgis -y
```

ERROR:

```
workhorse@workhorse-MS-7D91:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:3 https://apt.repos.intel.com/oneapi all InRelease                         
Get:4 https://debian.qgis.org/debian-ltr jammy InRelease [2,718 B]    
Err:4 https://debian.qgis.org/debian-ltr jammy InRelease   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D155B8E6A419C5BE
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Reading package lists... Done     
W: GPG error: https://debian.qgis.org/debian-ltr jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D155B8E6A419C5BE
E: The repository 'https://qgis.org/debian-ltr jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

qgis.sources:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian-ltr
Suites: jammy
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg"
```